# how to find Signal Strength of connected bluetooth devices

Tags: android, bluetooth, rssi

In one of my applications, I need to display all the wi-fi and Bluetooth devices which are paired to my mobile, and their signal strengths. With wi-fi, it's okay for me to display signal strength (RSSI). But I have a problem with the Bluetooth. I searched for some method which is suitable for this task; I found one method:

```
intent.getShortExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_RSSI, Short.MIN_VALUE);
```

But it is displaying only the new device RSSI which is not paired to my mobile. Is there any idea for getting all Bluetooth devices RSSI?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For bluetooth RSSI, you can read RSSI for connected devices, or perform a bluetooth discovery to check the RSSI for nearby devices.

Basically a bluetooth discovery is a broadcast to all stations within range to respond back. As each devices respons back, Android fires off an ACTION_FOUND intent. Within this intent you can getExtra EXTRA_RSSI to obtain the RSSI.

Note that not all bluetooth hardware supports RSSI.

Also Related: [Android IRC Office Hours Question About Android Bluetooth RSSI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149776/android-irc-office-hours-question-about-android-bluetooth-rssi)