# Get bluetooth signal strength

Tags: java, android

I want to get the Bluetooth signal strength of an another device which connected to my phone,

**How can I get the Bluetooth signal strength?**

I tried to search a lot over google and did not find any answer.

Does someone know how can I implement it?

this is myActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            String action = intent.getAction();
            if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                int rssi = intent.getShortExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_RSSI,Short.MIN_VALUE);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"  RSSI: " + rssi + "dBm", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    };

}
```

I also has a Bluetooth permission in my manifest file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020407/how-to-find-signal-strength-of-connected-bluetooth-devices

Comment: i already saw it, however there is no any example of how to find the signal strength..maybe can you help me?

Comment: I think your code is Ok. In order to see the Toast you need to execute a Discover first.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

To get the signal you can check Bluetooth RSSI, you can read RSSI for connected devices, or perform a Bluetooth discovery to check the RSSI for any  nearby devices.

Basically a Bluetooth discovery is a broadcast to all stations within range to respond back. As each devices responds back, Android fires off an ACTION_FOUND intent. Within this intent you can getExtra EXTRA_RSSI to obtain the RSSI.

Note that not all bluetooth hardware supports RSSI.

Also Related: [Android IRC Office Hours Question About Android Bluetooth RSSI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149776/android-irc-office-hours-question-about-android-bluetooth-rssi)
**here is a Bluetooth Classic broadcast receiver example**

```
private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String action = intent.getAction();
        if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            short rssi = intent.getShortExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_RSSI,Short.MIN_VALUE);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"  RSSI: " + rssi + "dBm", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: can you give me an example, how can i reed the RSSI and get from it the bluetooth  strength?

Comment: thanks alot, i wrote this code, however when i paired with device it does not show me in Toast the signal strength, do you have another way? i also add my activity to the main thread

Comment: EXTRA_RSSI value is a short type instead of int change it and then check

Comment: Don't forget to accept his answer if you're happy with it(The green icon left of the answer)

Comment: i will accept it, its still doesnt work for me...  @Arvind, the EXTRA_RSSI  value is short and not int in my code, i also updated my code(in the main thread) however it still does not work

Comment: I telling you to change it from short to int .Take into consideration that rssi values are usually negative (it
could be dBm )

Comment: i changed it to int instead of short, however still when i get paired with another device it does not show any Toast..do you have another suggestion?thanks alot

Comment: You forget to change Integer.MIN_VALUE

Comment: i changed it, still show me nothing...maybe something wrong with my code above?

Comment: I think your code is Ok. In order to see the Toast you need to execute a Discover first.

Answer (score 36):

I think your code is ok, but you need to implement `startDiscovery()` in order to see results.

The true is that `BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_RSSI` only works for discovering devices, when you connect to one of them you are not able any more to get its RSSI.

Here I developed a very simple sample of an Activity that permit you see the RSSI of the devices near to you. You first need to add a TextView and a Button to your layout, then enable the Bluetooth Adapter and then just click the button.

```
package com.in2apps.rssi;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class RSSIActivity extends Activity {

    private BluetoothAdapter BTAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_rssi);
        registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));

        Button boton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        boton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {
                BTAdapter.startDiscovery();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_rssi, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            String action = intent.getAction();
            if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                int rssi = intent.getShortExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_RSSI,Short.MIN_VALUE);
                String name = intent.getStringExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_NAME);
                TextView rssi_msg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                rssi_msg.setText(rssi_msg.getText() + name + " => " + rssi + "dBm\n");
            }
        }
    };
}
```

It looks this way:

[image: RSSI Detection - Android Example]

Comment: Can you check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31761416/connect-to-bluetooth-programmatically) please?

Answer (score 13):

The necessary API was introduced in API 18 (Android 4.3).  You need to call [`BluetoothGatt#readRemoteRssi()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt.html#readRemoteRssi()) to initiate the request.  The response shows up on the [`BluetoothCallback#onReadRemoteRssi()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCallback.html#onReadRemoteRssi(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt,%20int,%20int)) callback.  (That's the callback object that handles connect, discovery, characteristic reads, etc.)

The broadcast receiver stuff is no longer required.

Comment: How i can use this with Bluetooth Classic socket connection .

Comment: This answer is for BLE devices not for Classic Bluetooth

Answer (score 6):

You can get the signal strengh of a *[BluetoothDevice](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html)* using its rssi. This can be done using *[BluetoothAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html)* to get the bounded devices.

Once you have the one you are interested in, just call *[connectGatt()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#connectGatt(android.content.Context,%20boolean,%20android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCallback))* on it and define a new *[BluetoothGattCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCallback.html)*. This is an interface that provides few method to override. The two written below will allow you to have the rssi everytime the connection state changes.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  // Get the default bluetoothAdapter to store bonded devices into a Set of BluetoothDevice(s)
  BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
  // It will work if your bluetooth device is already bounded to your phone
  // If not, you can use the startDiscovery() method and connect to your device
  Set<BluetoothDevice> bluetoothDeviceSet = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

  for (BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice : bluetoothDeviceSet) {
    bluetoothDevice.connectGatt(this, true, new BluetoothGattCallback() {
      @Override
      public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
        super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState);
      }
      @Override
      public void onReadRemoteRssi(BluetoothGatt gatt, int rssi, int status) {
        if(status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS)
          Log.d("BluetoothRssi", String.format("BluetoothGat ReadRssi[%d]", rssi));
      }
    });
  }

}
```

NOTE : This sample requires a the following permission declared in your manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
```