# How fast can I obtain the RSSI-value from a bluetooth device?

Tags: android, bluetooth, rssi

I was wondering at; At what maximum rate would I be able to obtain the RSSI of Bluetooth device on my android phone? I have run a code identical to that given by Memochipan at the bottom of this thread:

[Get bluetooth signal strength](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15312858/get-bluetooth-signal-strength)

It simply turns on “discovery”-mode on the phone, which then goes to scan for Bluetooth devices. However, it takes about 10-20 seconds to get an update from a specific device, which is too much for, what I’m doing. So, is it even possible to get an update quicker? What stops the other Bluetooth device from sending a signal back to my phone sooner? Physical limitations? Also, from what I read, actually connecting to device won’t give me a “reliable” RSSI-value at all.
Thank you very much