# How to Get bluetooth signal strength (rssi) of connected bluetooth devices?

Tags: android, bluetooth, rssi

i want to get the bluetooth rssi of a another device which connected to my phone,

how can i get the bluetooth rssi?

i tried to search alot over stackoverflow/google and didnt find any answer, i found just the answer to get rssi of devices wich do not have any connection ! ([Get bluetooth signal strength](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15312858/get-bluetooth-signal-strength)).

but i need the rssi of the connected devices !

can you help me please.

thanks alot

Answer (score 2):

I was also looking for a solution and found this:

You can use the [`readRemoteRssi()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt.html#readRemoteRssi()) function of `BluetoothGatt`. This will cause an asynchronous call of your [`BluetoothGattCallback.onReadRemoteRssi`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCallback.html#onReadRemoteRssi(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt,%20int,%20int))