# Signal Strength of connected Bluetooth module from Android Application?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, hm-10

I want to know the connection strength of connected HM-10 Bluetooth module from my android. I cannot find any answer? Is it possible or not?

I checked this :
[How to Get bluetooth signal strength (rssi) of connected bluetooth devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26858227/how-to-get-bluetooth-signal-strength-rssi-of-connected-bluetooth-devices)

But that dosen't solve!!

Thanks

Comment: Checkout my code from github. I used an answer from stackoverflow, but sadly, can't remember it now : https://github.com/Aggarwal-Ankur/indoor_positioning_app/blob/master/main/src/main/java/com/aggarwalankur/indoor_positioning/core/ble/BLEScanHelper.java

Comment: Hey, thanks .. but HM-10 module does not transmit BLE packets once connected with Android. So in this case your code works?