# How to get bluetooth RSSI of some specified devices (only 2 or 3 devices) and use the specified rssi as a parameter?

Tags: android, eclipse, parameters, bluetooth, rssi

this is the first time I'm asking here, and I'm new to programming, so please pardon my ignorance..

I'm trying to make an application that will auto-connect my android to the specified bluetooth devices (arduino).

The parameter is the RSSI level of the specified bluetooth (I'm using 2 bluetooth) so that if :

**rssi1 = RSSI level of bluetooth A**

**rssi2 = RSSI level of bluetooth B**

what I want is if **rssi1 > rssi2** then my android will be connected to **bluetooth A**, and vice versa.

I am referencing to the code on the [Get bluetooth signal strength](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15312858/get-bluetooth-signal-strength) by Memochipan and I know that we can read the RSSI of some bluetooth devices while scanning, but I don't know how to make the RSSI as a parameter for my code.

thanks in advance

here's my code

```
    public class Btdisc extends Activity {
        BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
        OutputStream mmOutputStream;
        InputStream mmInputStream;
        String ruang1 = "20:14:11:26:03:71";
        String ruang2 = "28:BA:B5:E1:B8:C0";
        int limit = -58;
        int rssi1a;
        int rssi2a;
        int stat;

        private BluetoothAdapter BTAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        private Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_btdisc);
            registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));

            Button tombol = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            tombol.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    BTAdapter.startDiscovery();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.btdisc, menu);
            return true;
        }

        private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String action = intent.getAction();
                if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {

                     Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = BTAdapter.getBondedDevices();
                     if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
                        for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {

                    rssi1a = intent.getShortExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_RSSI,Short.MIN_VALUE);
                    if (device.getAddress().equals(ruang1))
                    {     
                        TextView rssi1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                        rssi1.setText( "Ruang 1"  + " => " + rssi1a + "dBm\n\n");

                    }
                    rssi2a = intent.getShortExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_RSSI,Short.MIN_VALUE);
                    if (device.getAddress().equals(ruang2))
                    {
                        TextView rssi2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                        rssi2.setText("Ruang 2" + " => " + rssi2a + "dBm\n\n");
                    }

            // try {
            //  btconnect();
                //stat = 1;
            //} catch (IOException e) {
                //stat = 0;
            //e.printStackTrace();
            //}

            }
        }
    }
    }


    void btconnect() throws IOException

    {


            if (!BTAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                Intent enableBluetooth = new Intent(
                        BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(enableBluetooth, 1);

            }

            Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = BTAdapter.getBondedDevices();
            if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
                for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {

                        if (device.getAddress().equals(ruang1) && rssi1a >= limit){
                        mmDevice = device;

                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");

            mmSocket = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);

            mmSocket.connect();
            mmOutputStream = mmSocket.getOutputStream();
            mmInputStream = mmSocket.getInputStream();

        };
};
};
`
```