# How to change the bluetooth low energy range in Android as programming?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, android-ble

Is it possible categorize the BLE into four proximity zones:

1. immediate (strong signal; usually up to a few centimeters)
2. near (medium sign; usually up to a few meters)
3. far (weak signal; more than    a few meters)
4. unknown ("hard to say", usually when the signal is very, very weak)

?

Answer (score 0):

I think something similar has been done in this post:

[Get bluetooth signal strength](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15312858/get-bluetooth-signal-strength)

You can also refer to this post:

https://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/20643/how-to-get-android-bluetooth-rssi-receiver-signal-strength