# Proximity Detection Between Two Phones (Android)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to figure out how I can send a notification to both phones when they reach a 6ft range from each other. I know that GPS is too wide of a range and so if wifi, I'm currently trying to use Bluetooth Low Energy because I heard it was more precise please let me know if there is any way I can go about this.

Comment: zigbee could do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [blog](https://blog.nordicsemi.com/getconnected/things-you-should-know-about-bluetooth-range), the signal range of each Bluetooth version varies. so it's difficult to find distance just by signal strength alone.

**Solution**: The proximity between the two devices can only be known when they are connected, as soon as they are connected request the user to stand 6 feet away from the other user and note the signal strength.
*note:* it won't be accurate. it totally depends on the environment

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15313104/9400127) is a thread to find the signal strength. Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you! ill look into it